# symbolicatecrash is unable to find any symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I'm running XCode 4.5.2 and am having problems getting symbolicatecrash to work.

Note that this is for an app and dsym that were NOT generated on my system, and aren't in an archive.

So far I've:

1. export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app sudo xcode-select
2. sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
3. cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources
4. ./symbolicatecrash -v -o test.txt ~/Downloads/OnDeckCrash/OnDeck_2012-11-26-152754_Andys-phone.crash ~/Downloads/OnDeckCrash/OnDeck.app.dSYM

This did NOT create a "test.txt".
It seems to be unable to find any symbols at all.
It reports something like this for every module:

```
...........fetching symbol file for CoreFoundation--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == E30FC309-DF7B-3C9F-8AC5-7F0F6047D65F"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
```

Note that the app package is in the same directory as the mSYM package.
I've also tried adding symbolicatecrash to my path, and executing from the directory where the .dSYM and .app are located.  That made no difference.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem today. In my case the mdfind was not able to search the Archives (/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/) folder. So what I did was went to System Preferences->Spotlight->Privacy, added and then removed the Archives folder. Restart Xcode or Re-symbolicate

mdfind is used in symbolicatecrash to find dsym relative to the crash file with uuid
in your case

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == E30FC309-DF7B-3C9F-8AC5-7F0F6047D65F"
```

you can also run

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *"
```

to list all the dsym locations mdfind knows. This will give you the idea if your dsym is in the list or not

Also run this for your dsym to get uuid of ur app

```
dwarfdump --uuid xxx.app.dSYM/| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -d '-'
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to [How can I tell Spotlight to index my .dSYM bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715303/how-can-i-tell-spotlight-to-index-my-dsym-bundles)

I've tried to force importation of dSYM in my ~/Library, but without success, so the answer is :

```
FINAL SOLUTION

Configure Xcode so that the archive folder is located outside of ~/Library.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you never connect crashed device to your computer, you don't have symbol files for this device. That's why symbolicatecrash cannot find dsym files for system libraries.

Just connect your device to computer and wait xcode to download symbol files.

Answer (score 0):

On line 4 the last argument should be the directory that contains the .app and the .dSYM. At least that is what I do when I run the `symbolicatecrash` script from the command line.

Comment: Well, that helped a little.  It still "can't find any unstripped binary..." for most of the symbols, but now it gets "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: ..." for my dSYM and app files.