# How does Xcode find the dSYM to match a crash file?

Tags: xcode, archive, symbolicate, dsym, xcarchive

I received a .crash file from a customer and need to link it to the correct dSYM file. The archive for this product/version was built by another developer using Xcode, and the .xcarchive file put into git for a rainy day (like today).

After reading [Analyzing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) and [Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) it isn't clear how this works.

I have done the following:

- open the Devices window, "View Device Logs" button
- drag the .crash file to the list (we drag a crash log from a different device/user onto our device - this seems wrong but AFAIK is what needs to be done)
- In Organizer/Archives, the archive for the needed version is NOT in my list. It was built on a different computer and I have not done anything to bring it to my environment yet
- Initially when I was viewing the crash file, it simply had the hex codes
- right-click and "Re-Symbolicate" the crash log that I added earlier
- Somehow Xcode now seems to know about about my archive. I see method and line number info now, but...

I'm not convinced this is working, and may be linked to the wrong thing.

Q: How does Xcode know about my xcarchive file that contains the dSYM for the version of the crash file? (I would expect it to have to be in the Organizer/Archives list, but isn't)

Q: Is there a better way to import the .crash file? (I would expect to be able to drag it into Organizer/Crashes, but apparently not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think Xcode uses Spotlight to find the correct dsym file, so it shouldn't matter where it is on your disk.

I think it runs this command:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"
```

You can also run this to list all dsym files Xcode can find at the moment:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *"
```

(Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355508/116862))

Comment: Thanks - That does seem to work and find the dSYM files I was wondering about. I'm surprised this isn't a bit more explicit, but I guess it is the way it is.